# vue.js : error unknown action type?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I created my store store/user.js

```
export const state = () => ({
      user: {},
    });
export const mutations = {

};
export const actions = {
  AUTH ({commit},{email, password}){
console.log('email, password =', email, password)
  }
};

export const getters = {};
```

component:

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="AUTH(model)">
  <input type="text"  required v-model.lazy = "model.email">
    <input type="password" required v-model.lazy = "model.password" >
</template>


<script>
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {

    data() {
      return {
        model:{
          email:" " ,
          password:" "

      }

      }
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['AUTH']),
}
}
```

In my component , I am trying to execute a vuex action from a module, but I am getting an error, even if this action is defined :

```
unknown action type: AUTH,
```

I don't have any idey about problem.

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import user from './modules/user.js'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide your code which creates the store? Are you using vuex modules?

Comment: Because you're using modules, it'll be [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434071/734040).

Comment: [nuxt] store/index.js should export a method which returns a Vuex instance.
i get err

Comment: When using modules mode in Nuxt, you don't create the store yourself. Instead, export the state, getters, mutations and actions.

Comment: i use nuxt . how to do it nuxt?

Comment: i fix  store/user.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `createNamespacedHelpers`:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

const { mapState, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('users')
```

[Binding helpers with namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

Otherwise, the mapping helpers need the full module namespace:

```
...mapActions([
  'users/AUTH'
])

// if you are only using one module in the component
...mapActions('users', [
  'AUTH'
])
```

**Nuxt**

You're mixing classic and modules mode. When using modules mode, Nuxt creates the store instance from the `index.js` file. You simply export the state, getters, mutations and actions. State should be exported as a function:

```
export const state = () => ({
  foo: 0,
  bar: 1
})
```

Any file within the `store` directory will be considered a module and Nuxt will automatically register it as a namespaced module.

```
- store
-- index.js // the store
-- users.js // module 'users'
-- foo.js // module 'foo'
```

The users module looks otherwise correct.

Make the following changes to your component:

```
// template
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">

// script
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
         auth: 'users/AUTH'
    }),
    submitForm () {
        this.auth(this.model)
    }
}
```

Comment: i get err Uncaught TypeError: _vm.AUTH is not a function

Comment: Try using `this.$store.dispatch('users/AUTH')`.

Comment: and  Property or method "AUTH" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: i fix but get fn.bind is not a function .

Comment: I don't see where `bind` is being used in any of the code you've posted.

Comment: I found a mistake. Thanks a lot for your help